# How to query for TimeLiner data from Forge API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-navisworks

I used the TimeLiner plugin for Navisworks to create a 4D timeline. I'm now trying to grab this TimeLiner data from the Forge API. When I log into BIM360, I'm able to load a model into the viewer and see all TimeLiner information within a browser. However, I don't see how I can accomplish this with the Forge API. Is there an available API for this? Or is there another way to grab this info?

[image: Example of TimeLiner data within BIM360]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Timeliner properties are not extracted by Forge service (which BIM 360 is running on), and also some other properties. This blog tells in detail:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/updates-navisworks-nwd-translation-engine-coming

Currently, we do have an advanced option to override default configurations to tell NWD/NWC translator if it needs to translate Timeliner properties. **BUT**, this option is about [Forge Model Derivative API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/) **ONLY**.

While in BIM360 Docs UI, there is no any plan to expose options to let users override default configurations when they upload files. So for now, users uploading NWD/NWC files to BIM 360 Docs will lose Timeliner properties. Consequently, you will have to open those files inside Navisworks to view Timeliner data or take advantage of the Navisworks API to extract the data inside Navisworks. We apologize for the inconvenience.

However, we have legged a wish **BIMPLT-698** with BIM360 engineering team to evaluate the possibility of adding options for end-user when they upload the model files. You're welcome to track the updates in the future via sending an email quoting this wish id to the Forge support channel.

**Note. Triggering your own translation job to override your desired translation configurations via [Forge Model Derivative API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/) on files uploaded to BIM360 will charge you for cloud credits. You will have to consider the extra costs if you want to do so, and see here for the pricing: https://forge.autodesk.com/pricing**